# Retrieve div id value using ExtJS

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs

Ok this might be an easy question but I think I am missing something obvious.  In my Sencha/ExtJS app I am trying to retrieve an ID value from a div as it is randomized, auto-generated by ExtJS.  So I've been mucking around with Chrome's Developer Tools to make the queries.  Here is what I am currently doing:

```
handler: function() {   
    var test = Ext.query("div#foo div.x-panel-body");

    // This is what I need to retrieve but since it changes I need the ID
    //addInput('ext-gen1059');
    addInput(test);
}
```

here is the relevant markup for the fieldset:

```
<div id="foo" class=" x-panel x-form-fieldset">
<div class="x-form-fieldset-title" id="ext-gen1078">Add Recipe</div>
<div class="x-panel-body" id="ext-gen1059">  **// this ID is what changes**
```

Am I missing something obvious in the DOM methods used by ExtJS?  Should I be using Ext.get, Ext.query, Ext.select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.query` returns an array of (vanilla) [DOM elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element). All you need is the [`id` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id):

```
addInput(test[0].id);
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote - this works well but when I successfully save, submit the form, or hide the form and try to add another field to form it fails.  Any ideas?

Comment: Which part fails - the `Ext.query` call, retrieving `test[0]`, retrieving the `id`, or the `addInput` call? What's the exact error that shows up in the console?

Comment: Matt - I see what happens now - when I add an ingredient input and close the form using form.hide() or when I simply "close" the form (it's a modal panel) the div value changes and I need to retrieve it by moving up a value in the array, i.e. addInput(newInput[1].id);   By the way, it fails silently -  no error in JS console but I can see divs created as I inspect elements, they just are not displayed - I hope that makes sense..?